# Create polygons based on GPS-logging points SQL 2008

Tags: sql, sql-server, gps, polygons

I'm using SQL Server 2008 and I want to create a database view in which polygons are created based on points in a results-table?

Some remarks:

- The results-table contains i.a. the columns 'ScanID', 'Location', 'Latitude', 'Longitude', 'Automatic'.
- The combination of a consecutive series of ScanID's and a value in the column 'Location' should result into unique polygons.
- The column 'Automatic' defines whether a specific point should be taken into account (1) or not (0).
- The first vertex of the polygon should be repeated in the end of the polygon-string to close the polygon. The results-table only contains GPS-logging points and doesn't repeat the first point.

Some representative sample data:

(7894560, 'Lake', '52.9891', '5.1206', 0),
(7894561, 'Lake', '52.9901', '5.1201', 1),
(7894562, 'Lake', '52.9901', '5.1211', 1),
(7894563, 'Lake', '52.9911', '5.1211', 1),
(7894564, 'Lake', '52.9911', '5.1201', 1),
(7894565, 'House', '52.9901', '5.1211', 1),
(7894566, 'House', '52.9901', '5.1221', 1),
(7894567, 'House', '52.9911', '5.1221', 1),
(7894568, 'House', '52.9911', '5.1211', 1),
(7894569, 'Lake', '52.9901', '5.1221', 1),
(7894570, 'Lake', '52.9901', '5.1231', 1),
(7894571, 'Lake', '52.9911', '5.1231', 1),
(7894572, 'Lake', '52.9911', '5.1221', 1);

Ideally the output would be formatted as follows:

(Location, Shape)
('Lake', 'POLYGON (52.9890 5.1201, 52.9901 5.1211, 52.9911 5.1211, 52.9911 5.1201, 52.9890 5.1201)')
('House', 'POLYGON (52.9901 5.1211, 52.9901 5.1221, 52.9911 5.1221, 52.9911 5.1211, 52.9901 5.1211)')
('Lake', 'POLYGON (52.9901 5.1221, 52.9901 5.1231, 52.9911 5.1231, 52.9911 5.1221, 52.9901 5.1221)')

I've got another database view in which I create linestrings by taking two consecutive points. The code I use there is:
GEOMETRY::STGeomFromText('LINESTRING(' + CONVERT(VARCHAR, 
CAST(t1.latitude AS decimal(20, 16))) + ' ' + CONVERT(VARCHAR, CAST(t1.longitude AS decimal(20, 16))) + ', ' + CONVERT(VARCHAR, CAST(t2.latitude AS decimal(20, 16))) 
+ ' ' + CONVERT(VARCHAR, CAST(t2.longitude AS decimal(20, 16))) + ')', 4326) AS Shape"
I don't think I should solve my problem by using and transforming this piece of code, but it gives some direction. Probably de piece 'GEOMETRY::STGeomFromText' or something like that should be used.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Can you give an example of what the output should look like?

Comment: Thanks for asking. I edited the question, which now has an output example.